# Dotnet Core - configuring lazy loading in startup

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I asked a question (got a -2 for my efforts but thats besides the point). The [only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60300405/5750758) indicated I should use lazyloading by adding it in StartUp.cs.

However, no matter what I do I cannot add this. I followed the direction of the link the author suggested as well as what the author did and in all cases I got the following.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition
>   for 'UseLazyLoadingProxies' and no accessible extension method
>   'UseLazyLoadingProxies' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   JobsLedger.API  C:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\1.0 -
>   AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.1\JobsLedger.API\Startup.cs    74  Active

If there is an assembly reference I wonder if someone might point me in the right direction.

This is what I currently have along with the modification as per the link the author for that question suggested.

```
    services.AddDbContext<CATALOGContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("CatalogConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("JobsLedger.CATALOG")));
    services.AddDbContext<DATAContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("TenantDbConnection"), a => a.MigrationsAssembly("JobsLedger.DATA")));
```

How do I configure these lines for ".UseLazyLoadingProxies" as its currently saying this is not available?

Comment: Have you added the [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/) Nuget package?

Comment: I hadn't so I did that and I am still not able to get the option.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the option"?

Comment: I finally got this working as once I added the package mentioned above I needed to change all linked entities so they had the "virtual" name which I did. Thanks DavidG

Comment: DavidG ...submit as answer so i can upvote, this helped me

Comment: @DavidG, great save, do as Jacob Alley suggests and submit as answer, I'll upvote too.

Comment: @DavidG, ditto on what everyone is saying. Add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 11):

Per the comments and my own research on this issue, add [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/) to your package as it contains the UseLazyLoading method you need to add to your DB Context options.

Comment: Side note - I don't actually recommend using lazy loading. I would prefer explicit loading statements within entity framework core such as .Include() or .Select() to ensure good performance. If you have a small database you can enable lazy loading no problem but larger databases should have explicit loads.